# split string to hash

Tags: regex, perl

I have some log messages like this:

```
foo=value bar="some other value" complex.key="something more \"complex\""
```

What is the easiest way to split such a string into a corresponding hash?

The expected output in this case would be:

```
{
  'foo' => 'value',
  'bar' => 'some other value',
  'complex.key' => 'something more "complex"'
}
```

Comment: @ikegami yes, quotes are escaped. (I included that case in the question now.)

Answer (score 3):

This is what [Text::ParseWords](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords) is for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Text::ParseWords;
use Data::Dumper;

my $in = 'foo=value bar="some other value" complex.key="something more \"complex\""';

my %hash = parse_line('[= ]', 0, $in);

say Dumper \%hash;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'complex.key' => 'something more "complex"',
          'foo' => 'value',
          'bar' => 'some other value'
        };
```

The cleverness all happens in `parse_line()`. Its three parameters are:

- A regex defining the delimiters of the fields in your input string (here, a space or "=")
- A flag indicating whether you want to keep the quotation marks around your strings
- Your input string

Comment: Note that this isn't a validating parser. For example, you get weird results for `my $in = 'foo=moo=x bar=mar';`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a validating parser, you can use the following:

```perl
my %escapes = (
   # "\\n" => "\n",
   # ...
);

# Operates on $_. Uses and updates pos($_).
sub parse_value {
   /\G ( [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* ) /xcgs   # Adjust as needed.
      and return $1;

   /\G " ( (?: [^"\\] | \\. )* ) " /xcgs
      and
         return
            $1 =~ s{
              \\ (?: (\W)|(.) )
            }{
               defined($1) ? $1 :
               defined($escapes{$2}) ? $escapes{$2} :
               do {
                  # Adjust as needed.
                  warn("Unrecognized escape \"\\$2\" at pos " . pos($_) ."\n");
                  "\\$2"
               }
            }xsegr;

    # return "";   # Uncomment if C<< foo= >> is allowed.

    die("Missing value pos " . pos($_) ."\n");
}

sub parse_attrs {
   my %attrs;
   my $leading_ws_required = 0;
   for ($_[0]) {
      while (1) {
         my $has_leading_ws = /\G \s+ /xcgs;

         /\G \z /xcgs
            and return \%attrs;

         $has_leading_ws or !$leading_ws_required
            or die("Whitespace expected at pos " . pos($_) . "\n");

         $leading_ws_required = 1;

         /\G ( [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* ) /xcgs   # Adjust as needed.
            or die("Key expected at pos " . pos($_) . "\n");

         # /\G \s+ /xcgs;   # Uncomment if C<< foo =bar >> is allowed.

         my $key = $1;

         /\G = /xcgs
            or die("\"=\" expected at pos " . pos($_) . "\n");

         # /\G \s+ /xcgs;   # Uncomment if C<< foo= bar >> is allowed.

         my $val = parse_value();

         !exists($attrs{$key})
            or warn("Duplicate value for key \"$key\" at pos " . pos($_) . "\n");

         $attrs{$key} = $val;
      }
   }
}

my $attrs = parse_attrs("...");
```

Comment: Feels *very* complex. What is the advantage over the soluting using Text::ParseWords?

Comment: As parsers go, this is actually a very simple one. /// As I mentioned, it validates, and the T::PW solution doesn't. I gave an example of what this means in the comments to the other answer. Do you want to make sure the input is correct? Then you don't want T::PW. Do you want it to parse 100% correctly? Then you don't want T::PW. Otherwise, go ahead.

Comment: @ikegami Did you write this for this question, or is it borrowed from somewhere?

Comment: @TLP From scratch. Why?

Comment: @ikegami Seems like a complicated project. Many edge cases to consider. Something one does not just write from scratch and expect to work with any input for a question like this. But perhaps it is something you wrote before that was suitable here.

Comment: @TLP, Re "*Many edge cases to consider.*", As evidence by the numerous comments giving options. :) /// Re "*But perhaps it is something you wrote before that was suitable here.*", Nah, it's not even tested :)

Comment: @TLP, Tested now. Four little mistakes (or->and, \w->\W, missing * in regex, missing /g)

Comment: @TLP, Re "*Something one does not just write from scratch and expect to work with any input for a question like this*", That's the whole idea, actually. There's no ready-made solution to parsing some arbitrary grammar. To properly do so requires writing a use-specific parser. A ready made one won't be as strict and/or won't be accurate (does it handle `\n` the same way? `\x##`? `\x{####}`? `\u####`? spaces around `=`? etc)

Comment: I guess it does not matter so much since the question is closed anyway.